How to import the average expression matrix for all detected genes in each cluster into Seurat？
I download a matrix which has 19 columns and the first column is gene names, other is cell cluster: 
In fact, I just want to plot the feature plot which like this: 
My idea is to use the function DotPlot in Seurat package to plot it. So how can I import this matrix into Seurat object or is there any other method?
